# UDP packets to Azure Event Hubs

Tags: udp, azure-eventhub

Does Azure Event Hub consume UDP packets?  I want to utilize Azure Event Hubs but it seems limited to only TCP.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, to send the data to Event Hubs, developers must publish the events via the AMQP or the HTTPS. UDP is a connectionless protocol, it seems not support in Azure Event Hubs.

For detailed information about Event Hubs protocol, please refer to this article: [AMQP 1.0 in Azure Service Bus and Event Hubs protocol guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-protocol-guide).